# Is there something like "Firebug" for Windows API?

Tags: windows, software-rec, firebug

I'm searching for a utility that can scan opened windows and show their properties, like Firebug in Firefox, but for Windows API.

I tried to search for it on the web, but no luck. Has anybody seen something like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Spy++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264396%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) comes included with Visual Studio.

> Spy++ (SPYXX.EXE) is a Win32-based utility that gives you a graphical view of the system’s processes, threads, windows, and window messages.
>
> Spy++ has a toolbar and hyperlinks to help you work faster. It also provides a Refresh command to update the active view, a Window Finder Tool to make spying easier, and a Font dialog box to customize view windows. Additionally, Spy++ saves and restores user preferences.

Use [Winspector](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Security/Security-Related/Winspector.shtml) as an alternative.